# How to use Three.Triangle() in three.js

Tags: javascript, html, three.js

Three.js has function called `THREE.Triangle()` and I would like to know how to use it.

Comment: Please add your code

Comment: I think you should be able to google this, anyways [here's](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Triangle) the documentation link.

Comment: Why is this a bad question?  I am curious about stuff when i have no idea what it is too.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I suspect the Triangle class may not be what you are expecting it to be; it is not a class to be used directly for drawing simple 2D Triangles.

---

The Triangle class is a math utility function for encapsulating triangles and doing calculations, which is useful when drawing surfaces.
A good more detailed explanation for usage of triangles in drawing surfaces: [Why do 3D engines primarily use triangles to draw surfaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6100528/why-are-there-always-triangles-used-in-a-3d-engine)

---

If you are just trying to draw a simple 2D triangle:

```
var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
var v1 = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
var v2 = new THREE.Vector3(30,0,0);
var v3 = new THREE.Vector3(30,30,0);

geom.vertices.push(v1);
geom.vertices.push(v2);
geom.vertices.push(v3);

geom.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2 ) );
geom.computeFaceNormals();

var mesh= new THREE.Mesh( geom, new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial() );
```

Another StackOverflow answer for this: [Basic 2D colored triangle using three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11020405/basic-2d-colored-triangle-using-)

---

Equivalent code using the Triangle class:

```
var geom = new THREE.Geometry();
var v1 = new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0);
var v2 = new THREE.Vector3(30,0,0);
var v3 = new THREE.Vector3(30,30,0);

var triangle = new THREE.Triangle( v1, v2, v3 );
var normal = triangle.normal();

// An example of getting the area from the Triangle class
console.log( 'Area of triangle is: '+ triangle.area() );

geom.vertices.push(triangle.a);
geom.vertices.push(triangle.b);
geom.vertices.push(triangle.c);

geom.faces.push( new THREE.Face3( 0, 1, 2, normal ) );
```

jsbin link to play with: http://jsbin.com/zatejelika/1/edit?html,css,js,output
Triangle class documentation link: http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Math/Triangle